# DHCPD ignoring my subnet declaration

Tags: centos, dhcp

`eth0`, my internal interface, has a static address of `10.0.0.1`. I also have an interface, `p4p1`, acting as my external interface. If it matters, my external interface is not physically connected and `iptables` is off/still being written.

`/etc/sysconfig/dhcpd`:

```
DHCPDARGS=eth0
```

subnet clause from `/etc/dhcpd.conf`:

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option routers 10.0.0.1;
  option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.1;
  option ntp-servers 10.0.0.1;
  default-lease-time 86400; # 1 day 
  max-lease-time 604800;    # 7 days
  use-host-decl-names on;
  ddns-updates on;

  use-host-decl-names on;
  allow unknown-clients;
  ignore client-updates;

  option domain-name "localdomain";
  ddns-domainname "localdomain";
  next-server 10.0.0.1;
  filename "pxelinux.0";

  group # known hosts
  {
    host host1.localdomain  {hardware ethernet [REDACTED]; fixed-address host1.localdomain;}
    host host2.localdomain  {hardware ethernet [REDACTED]; fixed-address host2.localdomain;}
  {

  pool
  {
    one-lease-per-client true;
    ping-check true;
    range 10.0.0.51 10.0.0.60;
  }
}
```

So, why am I still getting the "No subnet declaration" error message at launch?

```
No subnet declaration for eth0 (10.0.0.1).
** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
   you want, please write a subnet declaration
   in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
   to which interface eth0 is attached. **
```

**UPDATE 4/1 1900h**

Prior to tonight's experiments:

```
[root@father ~]# ip addr show dev eth0
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:e2:ba:2d:92:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::92e2:baff:fe2d:924d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I switched my internal network IP addresses to `192.168.100.0/24` with matching changes to `/etc/dhcpd.conf` for no change in behavior.

```
[root@father ~]# ip addr show dev eth0
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:e2:ba:2d:92:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::92e2:baff:fe2d:924d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[root@father ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p4p1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 p4p1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth0
```

Oh, hey! No gateway there! That's easy to fix with a `GATEWAY=192.168.0.1` in the `ifcfg-eth0` and `ifcfg-p4p1` files. `service network restart` and...

```
[root@father ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p4p1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 p4p1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p4p1
```

So, I have a gateway, but `service dhcpd start` fails with the same error.

Other notes:

- `p4p1` is not physically connected.
- `service dhcpd configtest` says `Syntax: OK`. So, this almost certainly is not a case of a misplaced brace.

Comment: For RHEL/CentOS 7 with `systemd`: you can make a copy of `/lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/` and specify the interface in the **Exec** line:  `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -user dhcpd -group dhcpd --no-pid eth0`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, can I get a "D'oh!" from the congregation!

In RHEL6 and derivatives, the dhcpd config file is now located at `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`, not `/etc/dhcpd.conf`. Moved the file and all is well.

Comment: Now it is working fine or you are facing any issue ?

Comment: It's working fine, now. And that bruise on my forehead is from where I was bashing my head on my desk...

Comment: Annoying, right? I just got bit by this.

Comment: When I searched for "centos install dhcpd" the centos.org result, which is the first one, is for centos 5 and refers to /etc/dhcpd.conf. It makes sense that there could be small but significant changes to how CentOS 6+ are designed, like this!

Answer (score 7):

The subnet mask that you have specify in `dhcpd.conf` must match your interface subnet mask.

Run:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0
```

You specified the subnet mask as `255.255.255.0`, this is most likely wrong. Change your `dhcpd.conf` to match your interface.

The interface where the DHCP server is listening must have an Static IP of the same subnet you are using in your DHCP configuration.

Comment: ifconfig reports the netmask as 255.255.255.0, which matches the NETMASK=255.255.255.0 setting I put in ifcfg-eth0.

Comment: what is your server IP and router, post output of `/sbin/route -n`

Comment: I've updated the main question with the information.

Comment: @dafydd Now it is working fine or you are facing any issue

Answer (score 0):

On RedHatEnterprise 8.3, my root cause was firewalld.
Even though firewalld had dhcp service enabled and was managing both interfaces, dhcpd issue went away when firewalld was stopped.
I made the following changes to /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml:

```
[root@lab-dns1 zones]# pwd
/etc/firewalld/zones
[root@lab-dns1 zones]# 
[root@lab-dns1 zones]# diff -c public.xml.20210304 public.xml
*** public.xml.20210304 2021-03-02 12:55:13.897419070 -0700
--- public.xml  2021-03-04 09:18:53.033552618 -0700
***************
*** 4,10 ****
    <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
    <service name="ssh"/>
    <service name="ntp"/>
-   <service name="dhcp"/>
    <rule family="ipv4">
      <source address="10.220.18.0/25"/>
      <port port="53" protocol="tcp"/>
--- 4,9 ----
***************
*** 25,28 ****
--- 24,37 ----
      <port port="53" protocol="udp"/>
      <accept/>
    </rule>
+   <rule family="ipv4">
+     <source address="10.220.18.0/25"/>
+     <port port="67" protocol="udp"/>
+     <accept/>
+   </rule>
+   <rule family="ipv4">
+     <source address="10.220.99.0/24"/>
+     <port port="67" protocol="udp"/>
+     <accept/>
+   </rule>
  </zone>
[root@lab-dns1 zones]#
```